# Elastisearch as session data storage?

Tags: php, session, elasticsearch

Is there any reason why one should not use elasticsearch as a session data storage for php ?

We're currently using mysql to store session data for this app, but as our user base grows, it becomes a pain to maintain and scale. 
We were thinking about migrating the sessions to redis or couchbase, but why not elasticsearch ?

The pros :

- To my understanding, elasticsearch is a very capable key/value store.
- We already have a robust & scalable cluster, so migration & maintenance is eased.
- ?

The cons :

- Nobody seems to be using elasticsearch as a session storage...
- ?

Comment: There's an express middleware that leverages [ES as session store](https://github.com/DrJest/express-elasticsearch-session) so definitely some people are doing it ;-)

Comment: Same thing [for Magento](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/elasticsearch-magento-session-storage-analyzer-zsolt-szalay)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: ElasticSearch is **NOT** key value storage. 
It's an **search engine**. 
It will help you index your data and find it fast and that's the best use case for it.

Sure, you can store your sessions there, but it's not built for it:

- Security has improved with ElasticSearch but I'd still not trust it to store sessions.
- If one of your clusters dies you might lose those sessions (depending on your architecture)
- ElasticSearch is quite memory hungry. If you're using it to just store sessions then you're literally burning money.
- Memcache + Redis are reliable, scalable and work with PHP out of the box (i.e. you can define session storage for those two in php.ini). They would also be as fast as ES if not faster.

tl;dr; you can use it, you can use database, or files, but there are better tools for the job.

Side Note: I've actually seen a contractor implement it for one of the projects we were running and it was one of the best examples of over-engineering I've ever come across. It took 10x less time to scrap it and implement the same logic using Memcache than it took him to produce that monstrosity.

Comment: I'm curious what the issue would be with your first point. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Regarding the second and third points, the OP said they already have a robust and scalable cluster, so that might be a non-issue.

Comment: Your fourth point is valid, though ;-) And in the [key-value store DB engines ranking](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking/key-value+store), ES is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

From 2016 but I still have benefits of this idea:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/elasticsearch-magento-session-storage-analyzer-zsolt-szalay/

Elasticsearch in not a key value server but still blazing fast and top on that you get much more. You can search in your session data, you can analyze them in real time. 
Might you don't need that for sure. BUT this is the advantage compare to a simple key-value server what designed to deliver fast and that part works well usually. :)

Hope helps and triggers you :)
Thanks